# Changing line spacing in QGIS expression string builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression

I'm using QGIS 3.22.11-Białowieża and, in the print composer, I need to split the title of the legend into two lines. With the expression string builder, I've written this simple code:

```
'Line 1' || '\n' || 'Line 2'
```

Is it possible to change the spacing between lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of the `Spacing` sub-menu in the item properties of the Legend, there is an option called `Line space`.

[image]